# Lock a statement in objective-c for atomic access

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to atomically execute following set of statements

```
            [inspectionLiteApi setBusinessObject:inspectionSourceObjectApi];
        if (![inspectionSourceObjectApi.inspectionLites containsObject:inspectionLiteApi])
            [inspectionSourceObjectApi addInspectionLitesObject:inspectionLiteApi];
```

These statement can be called from multiple thread. But i want each thread to access them atomically. What is the proper way. I have searched for `NSLock` but using `NSLock` has following issue:

> Warning: The NSLock class uses POSIX threads to implement its locking
>   behavior. When sending an unlock message to an NSLock object, you must
>   be sure that message is sent from the same thread that sent the
>   initial lock message. Unlocking a lock from a different thread can
>   result in undefined behavior.

Regarding the use of

`dispatch_semaphore_create`

`dispatch_semaphore_signal`
and

```
dispatch_release
```

I couldn't understand how to use them. Can any one guide me?

Comment: My preferred technique is not to lock anything at all, instead I temporarily drop back to the main thread with `dispatch_async()` then drop back to whatever thread I was on with `dispatch_async()` again. I've found locking can too easily lead to deadlock bugs, but async to the main thread and back always works perfectly. The main thread should never do anything longer than a split second so it's pretty much always available as an idle thread to drop onto for a moment. So there's usually no real performance penalty.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert But, there are multiple background threads accessing these statements.

Comment: "`NSLock` has thread safety issue." what?  It wouldn't be much use then would it...

Comment: @trojanfoe what i meant to say was From Apple Docs "Warning: The NSLock class uses POSIX threads to implement its locking behavior. When sending an unlock message to an NSLock object, you must be sure that message is sent from the same thread that sent the initial lock message. Unlocking a lock from a different thread can result in undefined behavior."

Comment: @Umair Does not look like an issue to me.  Also there is the `@synchronized` keyword.  It all depends on where that code is and how it's called, which you have not revealed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with locks if used correctly. I'm just saying I haven't ever found it necessary. I prefer to keep it simple and drop back to the main queue to get thread safety. As long as the main queue isn't being over-taxed this doesn't cause any performance problems. Remember that GCD will run your operations on the main thread if the main thread is idle, so you're not "wasting" a CPU core by doing what I'm proposing. I have never seen a performance problem with my technique. Usually it's faster than locks - because a lock will pause execution while dispatch_async() never pauses.

Comment: Threading is complicated, there are many _many_ tools available and they all have unique advantages. Without seeing your code, and without knowing for example how frequently you expect this code to execute (once a minute? once a second? one hundred thousand times a second?) we can't tell you what the best option is. One thing I will say is that `NSLock` is pretty much deprecated. It conforms to a standard born in the 1980's and has significant design flaws that do not exist in the grand central dispatch API.